# Is it possible to build a torrent client app for iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Someone assigned me a project in iOS to develop a torrent client app but the problem is that according to my knowledge there are no torrent clients available right now.

So the question is that is it possible to build such an app? I am not asking about publishing my app on app store I just want to build it (it's a university project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, see [popcorn time](https://popcorn-time.se/ios.html) or open source implementations on [github](https://github.com/search?q=torrent+language%3AObjective-C&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Objective-C)

But, as you probably know, Apple is likely not to publish such apps in the App Store due to questionable legal aspect.

Comment: You also need to think about how are you going to copy the file you torrented from the app to, say, your computer, lest you upload the file to Dropbox from the app and download it again from your computer--which makes torrenting from your computer in the first place the better option.

Comment: I would probably go with AirDrop or iTunes sharing, but yeah, I would be more worried about battery life and getting app out there (App Store is out of the question)

Comment: It has been 4 years ,any answer or workarounds to this on iOS 13.